# How to set the web root and hide app.php and app_dev.php in localhost using xampp and apache?

Tags: php, apache, symfony, xampp, localhost

I'm using **symfony** in my local computer for programming. its address is `http://localhost/RTL/web/app_dev.php/secure_area`.

How can I change this address to `http://localhost/secure_area`?

I mean removing `RTL/web/app_dev.php`.

I'm using xampp, apache and symfony 2.6.

other addresses could be something like these:

```
http://localhost/RTL/web/app_dev.php/login    =>     http://localhost/login
http://localhost/RTL/web/app_dev.php/logout   =>     http://localhost/logout
http://localhost/RTL/web/app_dev.php/admin    =>     http://localhost/admin
```

Comment: if you work on local environment why you want to remove app_dev.php? In any case RTL/web is simply to removing adding a directive like this: `DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/localhost/RTL/web"`on your virtual host. PS: is a common (and best) pratice to take the application folders out of the web root.

Comment: Thanks. If I want to deploy my application I should use **app.php** instead of **app_dev.php**. How can I remove that too???

Comment: with some rewrite rules [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281488/php-symfony2-hiding-app-php-from-the-url). Remember that you can't remove but only hide app.php from the url. Let me know if this works I will write the answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to the comments.

The RTL/web is removed adding the directive `DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/localhost/RTL/web"` on your virtual host file in apache.

Then you can hide app.php using these apache mod_rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$  
RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{CONTEXT_PREFIX}/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule .? - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]    
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}app.php [L]
```

then restart apache server to apply the modifications.